# Eclipse Kepler SR2 + Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

According to this [article](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler) It seems to be easy to add Java 8 feature to Eclipse. Somehow it doesn't work for me because I can't use the new syntax and I can't choose enviroment version 1.8 although JDK1.8 is installed and picked in eclipse' settings. There are no errors while installing feature or restarting eclipse.

Platform: Win7 x64

Eclipse version: Kepler SR2 Build 20140224-0627

Any Ideas?

Comment: assuming that you've followed the steps, my idea is to post the error message, if any, and inform the platform you're using and the eclipse version.

Comment: Open any Java project, go to properties, Java Compiler, Compiler Compliance Level. Do you see 1.8? (BTW I have same build on a win7 x32). Do you have JDK 1.8 installed?

Comment: I have JDK1.8 installed but no, I don't see 1.8 compilance level.

Answer (score 6):

I have created some kind of a graphical tutorial.

### Add Java 8 to Eclipse

- Install Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2
- Eclipse | Help | Install New Software...
- http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/
- Alternatively, install [Eclipse Luna 4.4 M7](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.4M7-201405010200/) and you do not have to install the Eclipse Kepler Java 8 patch.

[image]

Before the next step, if you still do not have JDK1.8.0 installed, go to *Add...* button and add your Java 8 JDK to your Eclipse.
You may ommit the step of changing the Javadoc location if you have not downloaded it to your local disk, it is just for faster access to Javadoc.

### Add Java 8 SDK to Installed JREs

- Eclipse | Window | Preferences

[image]

### Add Java 8 Support to your Project

- Eclipse | Project | Properties

[image]

Comment: I downloaded the most recent Eclipse Luna 4.4 and despite to the claim in that [article](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler) there’s no Java 8 support. Maybe it’s in the latest *sources*. Thankfully it works for me with Luna. Well, depends on how we define “working”…

Comment: @Holger: What *exactly* do you mean by "no Java 8 support"?

Comment: @Honza Zidek: There’s no compiler compliance level “1.8” in the list of choices, and no “Java8” in the list of execution environments.

Comment: @Holger: and you are speaking about Luna 4.4? I was confused by your comment as it seems that you are stating in your first sentence "in Luna4.4... there is not Java 8 support" and in the next sentence "it works for me with Luna".

Comment: I did exactly the same steps, except that I have only JDK8 installed so I didn't need to pick an enviroment in eclipse. I still can't choose compilance level 1.8.

Comment: @Honza Zidek: Damn, typo. It works for me with with *Kepler*. Well, I figured out that for *Luna*, I had to update the installation with the latest from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4milestones which is something different than “builds on our downloads page contain the Eclipse support for Java™ 8”. But the update fails with “Can’t delete eclipse.exe”.

Comment: @DanyloEsterman: try this http://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/add-java-8-support-to-eclipse-kepler/

Comment: Ok, downloaded Luna **M7** from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.4M7-201405010200/ works out-of-the-box, updating M6 to M7 did not. So for people not requiring Kepler, downloading 4.4M7 would be an alternative.

Comment: @HonzaZidek: your link leads to the same tutorial which you posted here (in terms of content).

Comment: @DanyloEsterman: Try the very exact flow again on a fresh computer. I believe you must do something differently (different version of Eclipse, not properly installed Kepler Java 8 patch, ...?)

Comment: @DanyloEsterman: I just downloaded a fresh new `eclipse-SDK-4.3.2-win32.zip` to reenact the procedure. Worked flawlessly. So whatever prevents it from working on your system must lie in an unknown detail.

Comment: @Holger:  My OS-X fresh 4.3.2 Eclipse download is failing in exactly the same way as DanyloEsterman.  It is the kepler patch itself that won't install.  It fails both through the http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/ as well as the MarketPlace.  It is surprising that an eclipse release that is rather mature has this glaring of an issue.  The remidiation page is kind-of useless, it just says basically "you're screwed" without at all explaining why.  Sigh.

Comment: @DanyloEsterman There is an eclipse download that has them pre-installed:  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-java8.php I don't know if it works.

Comment: @DanyloEsterman the http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-java8.php has got me 1.8 compiler compatibility and all that, so I can write Java8 code.  The bad news is that I can't install the groovy plug-in.  I suspect the Groovy Plug-in and the Java8 Eclipse Patch are slugging it out somehow.  The errors are too cryptic to make sense of.

Comment: The update site (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/) is not working in October 2021, any alternatives?

Comment: @Betalord Why would you want to install Eclipse Kepler in October 2021??? Install the newest version of Eclipse! This question and answer was relevant 7 years ago, when Eclipse still did not fully support the new features of Java 8. It is not a problem any more.

Comment: @HonzaZidek because I'm developing for Android using LibGDX and need to support some legacy libraries which do not compile with newer Eclipses since the ADT plugin has been abandoned.